# Rust IndexSet performance vs Python Tuple comparison?

Tags: python, performance, rust, set

I wrote the following code to implement automatic differentiation in Python and it worked well (slightly simplified here):

```py
class Dual:
    def __init__(
        self,
        real: float = 0.0,
        vars: tuple[str, ...] = (),
        dual: np.ndarray = np.ones(0),
    ):
        self.real, self.vars, self.dual = real, vars, dual

    def __add__(self, argument):
        if self.vars == argument.vars:
            Dual(self.real + argument.real, self.vars, self.dual + argument.dual)
        else:
            x, y = self._to_combined_vars(argument)
            return x + y

    def _to_combined_vars(self, other):
        combined_vars = sorted(list(set(self.vars).union(set(arg.vars))))
        x = self if combined_vars == self.vars else self._to_new_vars__(combined_vars)
        y = other if combined_vars == other.vars else other._to_new_vars__(combined_vars)
        return x, y

    def _to_new_vars(self, new_vars):
        dual = np.zeros(len(new_vars))
        ix_ = list(map(lambda x: new_vars.index(x), self.vars))
        dual[ix_] = self.dual
        return Dual(self.real, new_vars, dual)
```

I tried to replicated this in Rust as follows (again minimised),

```rust
use indexmap::set::IndexSet;
use ndarray::{Array1};
use auto_ops::{impl_op, impl_op_ex};

#[derive(Clone, Debug)]
pub struct Dual {
    pub real : f64,
    pub vars : IndexSet<String>,
    pub dual : Array1<f64>,
}
impl Dual {
    fn to_combined_vars(&self, other: &Dual) -> (Dual, Dual) {
        let comb_vars = IndexSet::from_iter(self.vars.union(&other.vars).map(|x| x.clone()));
        (self.to_new_vars(&comb_vars), other.to_new_vars(&comb_vars))
    }

    fn to_new_vars(&self, new_vars: &IndexSet<String>) -> Dual {
        let mut dual = Array::zeros(new_vars.len());
        for (i, index) in new_vars.iter().map(|x| self.vars.get_index_of(x)).enumerate() {
            match index {
                Some(value) => { dual[[i]] = self.dual[[value]] }
                None => {}
            }
        }
        Dual {vars: new_vars.clone(), real: self.real, dual}
    }

impl_op_ex!(+ |a: &Dual, b: &Dual| -> Dual {
    if a.vars.len() == b.vars.len() && a.vars.iter().zip(b.vars.iter()).all(|(a,b)| a==b) {
        Dual {real: a.real + b.real, dual: a.dual.clone() + b.dual.clone(), vars: a.vars.clone()}
    } else {
        let (x, y) = a.to_combined_vars(b);
        Dual {real: x.real + y.real, dual: x.dual + y.dual, vars: x.vars}
    }
});
```

The benchmarks, for the operation `dual1 + dual2` where each `dual` was a constructed datatype, were as follows:

In Rust:

- Float addition took 265 ps.
- Dual addition (with 100 **different** variables each) 97 us.
- Dual addition (with 1000 **different** variables each) 953 us.
- Dual addition (with 100 **similar** variables each) 13 us.  <-  4x worse than Python
- Dual addition (with 1000 **similar** variables each) 129 us.  <- 7x worse than Python

In Python:

- Float addition took 77 ns.
- Dual addition (with 100 **different** variables each) 353 us.
- Dual addition (with 1000 **different** variables each) 26.4 ms.
- Dual addition (with 100 **similar** variables each) 3.2 us.
- Dual addition (with 1000 **similar** variables each) 18.6 us.

I am puzzled why the Python implementation with similar variables is much faster than the rust implementation. In my program I typically use less than 100 variables and after a few iterations the variables are all aligned so these cases become the determining factors in speed.

I assume it is all in the lines

```py
if self.vars == argument.vars:
```

vs

```rust
if a.vars.len() == b.vars.len() && a.vars.iter().zip(b.vars.iter()).all(|(a,b)| a==b) {
```

But I dont know why this is materially slower or what I can do to improve it in Rust?

Comment: You're puzzled why highly optimized C code (assuming you use the classic python interpreter) is faster than presumably unoptimized (at least you did't specify release profile or other enabled optimizations)? Seems suspect and not indicative of a good benchmark.

Comment: Mandatory question - Did you add `--release` to your `cargo build`/`cargo run` command?

Comment: yes I ran `cargo build --release`

Comment: One thing that may be relevant is that when `dual1.vars == dual2.vars`, the Python code gives the sum object a reference to the same `dual1.vars` tuple (no copying needed), whereas the Rust code performs a clone.

Comment: There is no need to clone `a.dual` and `b.dual` in addition, just `&a.dual + &b.dual`. Also, the equivalent of Python tuple is `Vec`, not `IndexSet`. And why are you using `IndexSet` and not `HashSet`? And last note, if most times the values are the same, you may want to consider wrapping `vars` in `Rc` or `Arc`, as it does not change and this can save you a clone.

Comment: `HashSet` is unordered so one cannot associate the elements of the 1D dual vector with the variables in the other's dual vector. Other elementary operations are faster when using ndarrays and linear algebra, but the first step is to ensure all variables are ordered in the same manner. `IndexSet` also has some useful properties like unique elements and set operations over `Vec`

Comment: I changed Python to copy `dual1.vars` instead of reference and this then took 300us instead of 18.6us (1000 similar vars) so @slothrop is probably onto something significant here. The suggestion by @ChayimFriedman to use `Rc` or `Arc` where objects tend to converge to the having the same `vars` sounds worthy of research for me (I am new to rust).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After implementing `Rc` as per comment suggestion and converting the struct to

```rust
pub struct Dual {
    pub real : f64,
    pub vars : Rc<IndexSet<String>>,
    pub dual : Array1<f64>,
}
```

New timings were recorded in Rust as:

- Float addition took 265 ps <- 290x faster than Python.
- Dual addition (with 100 different variables each) 33 us <- 11x faster.
- Dual addition (with 1000 different variables each) 334 us <- 77x faster.
- Dual addition (with 100 similar variables each) 381 ns <- 8x faster.
- Dual addition (with 1000 similar variables each) 531 ns <- 35x faster.

This was because the comparison could be refactored to the following where checking for similarity was O(1).

```rust
impl_op_ex!(+ |a: &Dual, b: &Dual| -> Dual {
    if Rc::ptr_eq(&a.vars, &b.vars) {
        Dual {real: a.real + b.real, dual: &a.dual + &b.dual, vars: a.vars.clone()}
    }
    else {
        let (x, y) = a.to_rc_shared_vars(b);
        x + y
    }
});
```